# How to automatically scroll to a Selected treenode in primefaces using JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page with a huge tree component (scrollable) and an edit component where I can edit the selected node. After I edit the selected node in the edit window, I have an ajax event that updates the tree component.

My problem is that the tree updates 100% but the selected node is now scrolled out of view. How can I scroll back to the selected node. Or is there a way to update just the selected node in the tree instead of updating the tree completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same situation, here's my solution, based on JavaScript:

```
$('.scrollable-tree-container').each(function(index) {
    var position = $(this).find('.ui-state-highlight').position();
    if (typeof position != 'undefined') {
        $(this).scrollTop(position.top + $(this).scrollTop() - 300);
    }
});
```

How does it work?

- Specify the container providing the scroll bar
- Look for a highlighted node
- Read its position and scroll there

You might want to add additional selectors to avoid side effects on other components. I've subtracted 300px here since I had a total tree height of 800px. This way, the selected node will be somewhere in the middle (and not on top).
The undefined check is only necessary if you cannot asure that there's always one node selected when calling the function.

Comment: I use JSF to form my tree.At what place i added this line in my jsf?

Answer (score 1):

If the treenode is still selected you could try calling this after the edit

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ui-treenode-selected")[0].scrollIntoView()
```